# How to include image in Yii2 module

Tags: yii2, yii2-module

Cannot provide correct path to image in view inside of Yii2 module. Script and styles are loaded correctly.

**module structure:**

```
|-assets
|  ↳Asset.php
|-controllers
|-models
|-public
| |-css
| |  ↳styles.css
| |-js
| |  ↳script.js
| |-img
|    ↳image.gif
|-views
|  ↳view.php
|-Module.php
```

**Asset.php:**

```
class Asset extends AssetBundle {
    public $sourcePath = '@app/modules/scrapy/public';
    public $css = ['css/styles.css'];
    public $js = ['js/scrapy.js'];
}
```

**fragment of Module.php:**

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();
    $this->setAliases([
        '@modulename' => '@app/modules/module',
    ]);
}

public function getViewPath() {
    return '@modulename/views/';
}
```

Comment: Looks like your assets are published to a web accessible place, so the path to them is generated. To get the current one you need to go through `assetManager` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view file register the module asset:

```
<?php
// include module asset class
use app\modules\mycoolmodule\assets\Asset;

// register module asset in view and store it to a variable
$myAssetBundle = Asset::register($this);
?>
```

Now to access the image from img asset folder:

```
<img src="<?= $myAssetBundle->baseUrl . '/img/image.gif'; ?>" alt="image" />
```

So what you want is `$myAssetBundle->baseUrl` dynamic url of your asset bundle.

**PS:**
There are differences between `app` assets and `module|widgets` assets:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3048

Comment: You should probably use `\yii\helpers\Url::to($myAssetBundle->baseUrl . '/img/image.gif');` because `$baseUrl` property might contain an alias.

Comment: For modules `$baseUrl` is not set, is set the `$sourcePath`